# How to call a template member function in a template base class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, using, member-functions

When calling a non-templated member function in a base class one can import its name with `using` into the derived class and then use it. **Is this also possible for template member functions in a base class?**

Just with `using` it does not work (with g++-snapshot-20110219 -std=c++0x):

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
  template <typename T2> void f() {  }
};

template <typename T>
struct B : A<T> {
  using A<T>::f;

  template <typename T2> void g() {
    // g++ throws an error for the following line: expected primary expression before `>`
    f<T2>();
  }
};

int main() {
  B<float> b;
  b.g<int>();
}
```

I know that prefixing the base class explicitly as in

```
    A<T>::template f<T2>();
```

works fine, but the question is: is it possible without and with a simple using declaration (just as it does for the case where `f` is not a template function)?

In case this is not possible, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 10):

this works (pun intended): `this->template f<T2>();`

So does

```
template <typename T>
struct B : A<T> {
  template <typename T2> void f()
  { return A<T>::template f<T2>(); }

  template <typename T2> void g() {
    f<T2>();
  }
};
```

---

Why `using` doesn't work on template-dependent template functions is quite simple -- the grammar doesn't allow for the required keywords in that context.

Comment: Thanks, but both solutions do not really answer the question, as both are not simpler than saying `A<T>::template f<T2>()` in the first place.

Comment: I think `this` is simpler, although that's a matter of taste of course.  But it also allows virtual functions to be work as expected (although I see that is not an issue here).

Comment: @Lars: `using` is not simpler than `A<T>::template f<T2>()`... unless you are calling `f()` many times.  In which case the wrapper function is also a simplification.

Comment: I disagree. Of course I have the case in mind where you have many calls to `f`, not just one. So repeating `A<T>::template` or `this->template` all over the code is not very appealing. The wrapper solution is more complex than `using` because a) it is much longer, but more important b) you have to repeat the signature of `f`, so whenever you change `f` in the base class you have to do changes accordingly in the inheriting class (or: in *all* 10 inheriting classes...). I guess this is the reason why we have the `using` declaration at all. But why does it not work for templates?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use:

> `this->A<T>::template f<T2>();`

or:

> `this->B::template f<T2>();`